# Error en Java con java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, array

Hola tengo un problema y no se que significa, estoy haciendo una tarea.

**Se requiere de un programa que permita capturar e imprimir los datos de
dos cuentas de correo electronico. Cada dato de la cuenta de correo (Id,
dominio y password) dede digitarse por separado. Al imprimirse la cuenta
los datos de ID y dominio deben aparecer unidos. Por ejemplo:
zelaya.luis@gmail.com**

pero cuando estoy tomando la info y guardandola en cada atributo de la clase Correo me sale este error:

*Introduzca el ID del correo: alejandro

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at taller1_progra4_2.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Java Result: 1*

```
package taller1_progra4_2;


public class Correo {


    String iD;
    String password;
    String dominio;


    public String getiD() {
        return iD;
    }

    public void setiD(String iD) {
        this.iD = iD;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getDominio() {
        return dominio;
    }

    public void setDominio(String dominio) {
        this.dominio = dominio;
    }


    public Correo() {
    }
    public Correo(String iD, String password, String dominio) {
        this.iD = iD;
        this.password = password;
        this.dominio = dominio;
    }


}



package taller1_progra4_2;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Correo correos[] = new Correo[10];
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);


        int contador = 0;
            while(contador <= 3){    
                for (int iterador = 1; iterador <= 3; iterador++) {
                    switch(iterador){

                        case 1:{
                            System.out.print("Introduzca el ID del correo: ");
                            String iD = teclado.nextLine();
                            correos[1].setiD(iD);
                            break;
                        }
                        case 2:{
                            System.out.println("Introduzca el dominio del correo: ");
                            String dominio = teclado.nextLine();
                            correos[2].setDominio(dominio);
                            break;
                        }
                        case 3:{
                            System.out.println("Introduzca la contraseña: ");
                            String password = teclado.nextLine();
                            correos[3].setPassword(password);
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
                contador += 1;
            }

            Arrays.toString(correos);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que estás intentando llamar a un método de un objeto de tipo `Correo`dentro del arreglo `correos` pero dicho objeto que no existe. O lo que es lo mismo, la referencia que obtienes al acceder a arreglo es siempre `null` puesto que inicializas este (`Correo correos[] = new Correo[10];`) pero no el contenido de cada una de sus posiciones (algo como esto: `correos[0] = new Correo();`).

Además tienes otro problema con la lógica de tu programa. El bucle `for` es completamente innecesario, puesto que sabes que siempre son 3 los datos que tienes que solicitar para cada correo (quizás si lo utilizaras para validar las entradas tendría un poco de sentido, pero no es para lo que lo empleas y si fuera así te recomendaría un `while`) por lo que iterar en este caso no aporta nada. Por otra parte, en cada iteración accedes a las mismas 3 posiciones del arreglo para almacenar los datos entrados.

Con esto provocarías (en caso de que cada posición del arreglo conteniera una referencia diferente de `null`) que el objeto en el ínice 0 del arreglo almacenara el último `ID` introducido, el del índice 2 el último `dominio` y el del índice 3 el último `password`. El resto de índice no almacenarían datos.

Espero haberme hecho entender.

La solución sería algo como esto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Correo correos[] = new Correo[10];
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int contador = 0; contador < 10, ++contador) {
        System.out.print("Introduzca el ID del correo: ");
        String iD = teclado.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduzca el dominio del correo: ");
        String dominio = teclado.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduzca la contraseña: ");
        String password = teclado.nextLine();

        correos[contador] = new Correo(iD, password, dominio);
    }

    Arrays.toString(correos);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias sr

Comment: Un placer porder ayudarte.Saludos